# How to set the different height of columns in a grid?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm using Tailwind CSS for my project. I'm stuck with a minor problem. I have a 3-column grid and I want to set different heights for each column.

I have tried this code

```
    <div class="grid grid-cols-3 grid-rows-2 gap-2">
    <div class="bg-green-200 col-span-full h-auto">Box1</div>
    <div class="bg-white rounded-md shadow-sm h-[40px]">Box2</div>
    <div class="bg-white rounded-md shadow-sm h-auto">Box3</div>
    <div class="bg-white rounded-md shadow-sm h-[250px]">Box4</div>
    </div>
```

In the above code when I set the height to a specific item within the grid it applies to all remaining items for example if I set `h-10` to Box1 it will be applied to all remaining boxes.

Here is what I'm looking for, I want to set these specific heights -

Box1 - h-auto

Box2 - h-[40px]

Box3 - h-auto

Box4 - h-[250px]

Comment: It is working fine here https://play.tailwindcss.com/aW41djUVQp

Comment: h-auto will set the height of the cell to highest height grid cell

Comment: @buzz Yes it is but when applying the styles to other boxes Box1 changes itself

Comment: It is because the Box1 has h-auto which means auto height , which would take the height of the cell which has highest height in the entire grid, So if you change height of Box4 it will change the divs having h-auto width because the now the highest height is changed which reflects to all the divs which has h-auto

Comment: You want the grid to not have the gap when Box1's height is decreased. that is what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question,

> when I set the height to a specific item within the grid it applies to all remaining items for example if I set h-10 to Box1 it will be applied to all remaining boxes.

But ,in the following code I have changed the height of Box1 to `h-10` , which is not changing any div's height!

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-3 grid-rows-2 gap-2">
  <div class="col-span-full h-10 bg-green-200">Box1</div>
  <div class="h-[40px] rounded-md bg-blue-500 shadow-sm">Box2</div>
  <div class="h-auto rounded-md bg-orange-400 shadow-sm">Box3</div>
  <div class="h-[250px] rounded-md bg-amber-200 shadow-sm">Box4</div>
</div>
```

#### Before

###### Box1 => `h-auto`

[image]

#### After

###### Box1 => `h-10`

[image]

What are you actually looking for ? Can you be precise.

Comment: Hi thanks . This is what i want but still we can see space below box 1 . How to deal with that ?

Comment: Okay, now i understand your question. I'll get back to you in a while

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution to this , please ?